# Is there a "add to homescreen" webapp on Android (like in iOS)

Tags: android, html, web-applications

A webapp on iOS is basically a headless browser.

Is there something similar on Android?

As far as I understand it, you can only put bookmarks on the homescreen. Is that correct?

Note: Wrapping to something native on not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to add shortcuts (apps, bookmarks, etc) to the Android homescreen programmatically. All homescreen "additions" must be added via the launcher.

Comment: Correct, you could push the user to add to home screen via http://code.google.com/p/mobile-bookmark-bubble/ though

Comment: Right, but this homescreen icon is only a bookmark which opens the browser, right? Unlike on iOS...

Comment: Correct, you will achieve something like the web app view in iOS. From here on you either go with phonegap, or you keep using the default browser view.

Comment: Or you have your real App register an Intent-filter, intercept, and consume the URI request. User would have option to open your App or view in browser. If viewed in browser, your website could respond with JavaScript that sets the window location to a custom URI for which your App also has an Intent-filter registered. If you can have the original bookmark fire off that custom URI, then you could avoid the part where User gets to choose between your App or Browser.

Comment: is this answer even correct?  Straight from the referenced page: "The current implementation of this library specifically targets Mobile Safari, the web browser used on iPhone and iPad devices." ... Just sayin.

Comment: Sounds like you're reading from the iOS reference. The question was "can the I do it on Android?"

Answer (score 0):

Chrome for Android now lets you add homescreen shortcuts, which will open your web page as a web app (hides browser controls) - https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/installtohomescreen